# ¿Qué significa las letras que van antes de los campos de la tabla?

Tags: sql

Que significa las letras `a.` o `b.` que están antes de el nombre del campo y después del nombre de la tabla.

[image: .]

Comment: Saludos. Se conocen como **alias**; es usado para simplificar/sustituir en una consulta el nombre de la tabla; también usado para los campos; aunque el lenguaje lo permite lo normal es que entre estos datos hay una **AS** implícito.

Comment: Son un alias. Le dices a `pc` que será conocido también como a y product como b.

Answer (score 1):

Son alias o como se diría, una forma de nombrar una columna o una tabla.

Puede utilizarse con la palabra reservada **AS** seguido del alias o simplemente el alias despues del nombre de la tabla o la columna:

**Ejemplo de alias a una columna:**

```
SELECT mi_tabla.id AS mi_id FROM mi_tabla

-- También puedes escribir:

SELECT mi_tabla.id mi_id FROM mi_tabla
```

En este caso estoy agregando un alias a la columna **id** para llamarla desde ahora **mi_id**.

**Ejemplo de alias a una tabla:**

Imagina que tienes esta consulta:

```
SELECT mi_tabla.id, mi_tabla.nombre FROM mi_tabla;
```

En este caso utilizamos *mi_tabla* para llamar al campo, pero podemos ponerle un alias en este caso le llamaremos **A**, la misma consulta anterior con alias se vería de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT A.id, A.nombre FROM mi_tabla AS A;

-- También puedes escribir:

SELECT A.id, A.nombre FROM mi_tabla A;
```

Como ves en este ejemplo solo cambiamos la forma de llamar a los campos como si le cambiáramos el nombre a la tabla, ojo que no le cambiamos el nombre simplemente le agregamos otra forma de llamarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Son alias de las tablas. Se utilizan para no tener que escribir el nombre completo de la tabla al identificar las columnas. Una buena práctica es usar un alias que tenga relación con el nombre de la tabla (usualmente las iniciales) y no un simple consecutivo de letras. Otra buena práctica es utilizar la palabra `AS` para indicar que es un alias.

Otras buena prácticas, son utilizar las clausulas `JOIN` en vez de separar las tablas por comas y terminar las sentencias con punto y coma (;).

Dejo un ejemplo de como escribiría esta consulta.

```
SELECT  pc.model        AS modelo,
        MAX( pc.price)  AS precio,
        pr.maker        AS fabricante
FROM        pc --No usamos alias porque el nombre es suficientemente corto
INNER JOIN  product AS pr ON pc.model = pr.model
GROUP BY pc.model,
         pr.maker;
```